# Word for being intentionally humourous and dense to misrepresent a point

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What's that word for when somebody in an argument is being intentionally humourous and dense to misrepresent a point ? Thank you very much

Comment: It might be "facetious"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answer was given in a comment, so creating this as Community Wiki)

The word requested is *facetious.*  The definitions [given by M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facetious) are:

> 1 : joking or jesting often inappropriately : WAGGISH
>   // *just being facetious*
>
> 2 : meant to be humorous or funny : not serious
>   // *a facetious remark*

Answer (score 2):

There's also 'flippant' which means to be intentionally humourous and dense without taking the point seriously. To be facetious you need to actually take the point seriously enough to bother making an effort to misrepresent it, so I guess being facetious is harder work than being flippant ;)